# Filtered list of items in column A if item x is in any column from B to X

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I’m working on an Inventory system for a restaurant chain with a large number of recipes and their corresponding ingredients. I have an excel sheet  with all the recipe names in column A, and columns B and onwards have the ingredients for each recipe (A1 = “Chicken Noodle Soup”, A2 = “Chicken Stock”, A3 = “Noodles”, etc.). Some recipes have only one ingredient, others can have more than 10.

I’m trying to get a list of all recipes a given ingredient is used in, as a way to clean up the ingredients list to remove those that are no longer used over time. I have a separate sheet with all the ingredients in column A, and have been trying to use the FILTER function along with transpose to fill columns B and onwards with the recipes from the recipes sheet, but the only way I’ve figured out how to do it seems extremely clunky:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(‘Recipes’!A1:A8,(‘Recipes’!B1:B8='Inventory Items'!A1)+‘Recipes’!C1:C8='Inventory Items'!A1)+‘Recipes’!D1:D8='Inventory Items'!A1))
```

I’ve found that I have to check each column independently, which as you can imagine for a sheet that has some recipes with more than 10 columns (and may have new recipes with even more ingredients added in the future), this solution is extremely clunky to work with and update, though it does yield the desired result.

Is there another way to do this? I would love to just be able to set the INCLUDE variable to just ‘Recipes’!B2:M8 for example but this throws a #VALUE error.

Comment: A representative data sample, posted as **text which can be copy/pasted** along with a screenshot of the expected results from that data, would better encourage people to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table25"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),
    
    col1 = Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"){0},
    
//unpivot to produce a two column display
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", 
        {col1}, "Attribute", "Ingredients"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

//Group by ingredients and output a list of applicable recipes
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Ingredients"}, {
        {"Recipes", each Text.Combine(Table.Column(_,col1),"; "), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***Sample Data***
[image]

***Results from above data***
[image]